# Is there alternative editors to ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, editor

same as title suggest, I have recently got into the asp.net business and I was wondering if there are better code editors available or better yet just simpler/more instinctive shortcuts and plugins for VS 2010 or VS 2012 as I have problems getting used to the navigation around the projects.

Comment: Resharper is great help.

Comment: That's beautifully ironic as "JustCode" is the name of a Telerik's product that competes with Resharper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio is by far the best IDE for .NET. There are many plugins that will help you be more productive. In addition to ReSharper, these are some of my favorites:

[Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/)

[Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd?SRC=VSIDE)

Comment: +1 I used to LOVE PPT.  Glad they finally made a VS2012 version.  If I didn't have Resharper it would definitely be my backup choice.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio is by far the most powerful IDE that I have used.  I've used Netbeans, Eclipse, MyEclipse, and Dreamweaver, although not for .NET, and none of them seemed to offer as much power and flexibility in my opinion.

You could give Sharp Develop a try.  http://www.icsharpcode.net/.  It's decent, but I vastly prefer Visual Studio.

Also, as far as plugins go, if you want to drop the money for Resharper, it will make your life vastly easier.

Comment: Yeah VS+R# is going to be hard to beat.

Answer (score 2):

You could also check out [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com).

Not nearly as powerful as Visual Studio (+ ReSharper), but a nice and really lightweight alternative. As part of the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com), it also runs on Linux, Windows and Mac OSX. And it uses very little disk space compared to VS.  Here is a [simple comparison](http://development-software.findthebest.com/compare/9-11/Visual-Studio-vs-MonoDevelop).